# AWS: S3 bucket policy with Textraxt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

I want to give AWS Textract access to use my specific S3 bucket but struggling to find the ideal bucket policy.

After doing some research found that the [aws:CalledVia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) function may be appropriate but don't know how to make the policy.

Would appreciate any help with how the policy should look like. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Textract doesn't support the CalledVia as far as I know, but try using the userid of the IAM role instead.  See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

To get the userid for the IAM role you just get the role details using the AWS CLI.